# ¿Cómo accedo a mas de un campo con la relación uno a muchos ? django

Tags: python, django-models

Hola soy nuevo con django espero que me puedan ayudar.
Necesito acceder a dos campos del modelo provedor( id_provedor y nombre_provedor) con foreignkey desde el modelo Operacionimprtacion para poder manipularlos desde form por separado.

mi models.py:

```
class Provedor(models.Model):
id_provedor = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
nombre_provedor = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'provedor'
    verbose_name_plural="Provedores"

def __str__(self):
    return "%s, %s" % (self.id_provedor, self.nombre_provedor)


class OperacionImportacion(models.Model):
    
    Provedor = models.ForeignKey(Provedor, on_delete= models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)    
     

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Operacion_importacion'
```

Una solución que pensé pero me da error es la siguiente:

```
class OperacionImportacion(models.Model):    
    id_provedor = models.ForeignKey(Provedor.id_provedor, on_delete= models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)    
    nombre_provedor=models.ForeignKey(Provedor.nombre_provedor, on_delete= models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
   
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Operacion_importacion'
```

el error que me da es:

```
AssertionError: ForeignKey(<django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x0000018B2DA51360>) is invalid. 
First parameter to ForeignKey must be either a model, a model name, or the string 'self'
```

Answer (score 0):

para acceder a los campos del modelo de la relacion se utiliza __.

Ten en cuenta que el modelo debe tener una primary key. Tambien procura que el nombre de las columnas este en minusculas.

Algo como esto:

```
class OperacionImportacion(models.Model):
    id_operacion_importacion = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    provedor = models.ForeignKey(Provedor, on_delete= models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True) # <- nombre en minusculas

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Operacion_importacion'
```

Por ejemplo, si tienes un objeto de OperacionImportacion y quieres obtener informacion de Provedor harias algo como esto:

```
oi = OperacionImportacion.objects.get(pk=1)
print(oi__provedor__nombre_provedor)
```